# display data only and frequently when it is update in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I know how to display data with javascript using "onclick()","keyup()".... etc.It is also possible to display data with above function with set time.
But I want to show data on my web page instant when database table affected. Is it possible

Answer (score 0):

You can change something after a set time using
`setTimeout()`
setTimeout takes two arguments, a callback and the delay in milliseconds, for example
`setTimeout(function(){console.log("Hello World!")}, 1000)` will output "Hello World!" in the console after one second.

To bind the delay to the changing of the table I'd recommend calling it in the function that changes the table in the first place.

Comment: But, I want to know is it possible without set interval or setTimeout(). Can javascript has any function which can realize any change in table

Comment: Could you give us more clarification on what you exactly want? I don't really understand if its a table on the backend you're updating and if you already have some way to track that on the frontend or not.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible ,

first , use ajax ( jQuery.ajax())  for get data and set in website
sacand use setInterval()

like this :

```
setInterval(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/test.php',
                    data: {'data': 1 , 'data2':2},
                    success: function (response) {
                        /// set data
                        }

                    }
                });

            }, 1000);
```

Comment: But, I want to know is it possible without set interval or setTimeout(). Can javascript has any function which can realize any change in table